# Pygame rectangle/bullet not being appended to a list or even spawned

Tags: python, pygame

I **created a list to see whether any rectangles(bullets) are being spawned** when I press Left CTRL(for the player or plyr), or Right CTRL (for the other player, referred to as enmy). But **nothing is being appended to the list**

```
import pygame as pg
import os

WIDTH,HEIGHT=900,500
FPS = 60
WIN = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("Death")
ship_size = (55,40)

yellship = pg.transform.rotate(pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets','spaceship_yellow.png')),ship_size),90)
plyr_strt = (200,200)
plyr_hp = 1
plyr_vel = 3
plyr_bullet_cap = 10
plyr_bullet_vel = 7

redship = pg.transform.rotate(pg.transform.scale(pg.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets','spaceship_red.png')),ship_size),270)
enmy_strt = (600,200)
enmy_hp = 1
enmy_vel = 3
enmy_bullet_cap = 10
enmy_bullet_vel = 7

#IMPORTANT A LITTLE FURTHER DOWN*

def Player_Controls(keys_pressed,player):
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_a]:
        player.x -= plyr_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_d]:
        player.x += plyr_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_w]:
        player.y -= plyr_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_s]:
        player.y += plyr_vel
        
def Enemy_Controls(keys_pressed,enemy):
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_LEFT]:
        enemy.x -= enmy_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        enemy.x += enmy_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_UP]:
        enemy.y -= enmy_vel
    if keys_pressed[pg.K_DOWN]:
        enemy.y += enmy_vel

#Main game loop
def main():
    plyr = pg.Rect(plyr_strt,ship_size)
    enmy = pg.Rect(enmy_strt,ship_size)
    plyr_bullets = []
    enmy_bullets = []
    run = True
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

            # RIGHT HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pg.K_LCTRL:
                    plyr_bullet = pg.Rect(plyr.x + ship_size[1],plyr.y + ship_size[0]/2,10,5)
                    plyr_bullets.append(plyr_bullet)

                if event.type == pg.K_RCTRL:
                    enmy_bullet = pg.Rect(enmy.x,enmy.y + ship_size[0]/2,10,5)
                    enmy_bullets.append(enmy_bullet)
        
        print(enmy_bullets,plyr_bullets)
        keys_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
        Player_Controls(keys_pressed,plyr)
        Enemy_Controls(keys_pressed,enmy)
        draw_win(plyr,enmy)

    pg.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There are no problems with the images I'm using.

I'm all ears to any suggestions.

Please don't be too harsh on me, still just a newbie when it comes to python and pygame.

Comment: I think that after checking that the event type is of type KEYDOWN, you should be checking which key was pressed (not type). Thus,I think that you should replace `if event.type == pg.K_LCTRL:` by `if event.key == pg.K_LCTRL:`. The same happens with the if related to `pg.K_RCTRL`.

Comment: According to your logic, both `event.type == pg.KEYDOWN` and `event.type == pg.K_LCTRL` have to be `True` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks a small "typo" when checking the pressed key.

On the one hand, `event.type` returns the type of the event. In your example, the only event type you are interested in is `KEYDOWN`. On the other hand, `event.key` returns the key that triggered the event. In your example, the only keys you are interested in are `K_LCTRL` and `K_RCTRL`.

Thus, your code should look like:

```
# RIGHT HERE IS THE PROBLEM
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_LCTRL:
        # Actions when left control is pressed
    if event.key == pg.K_RCTRL:
        # Actions when right control is pressed
```